# How to get a reference to Application in Android test code

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

I have below ViewModel class:

```
@Singleton
class CatalogViewModel
@Inject constructor(application: Application,
                    private val catalogService: CatalogService,
                    private val databaseManager: DatabaseManager
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
}
```

I have this test class:

```
public class CatalogViewModelTest {

    private CatalogViewModel viewModel;

    @Mock
    private CatalogService service;

    @Mock
    private DatabaseManager databaseManager;


    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        viewModel = Mockito.spy(new CatalogViewModel(????, service, databaseManager));

    }
}
```

I am wondering how to get a reference to the Application in my test code. In the application itself it is easy ofcourse.

Comment: Try@Mock
   private Application applicationMock;

Answer (score 0):

According to Clean architecture approach your ViewModel code have not to contain any Framework related code. Especially reference on Application. 
CatalogService and DatabaseManager is not a part of Presentation. Create UseCase or Interactor, inject it in viewModel, use Repository pattern, inject it in UseCase or Interactor, inject your CatalogService and DatabaseManager into your repository and do all necessary work there.

This link may be helpful: https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-implement-a-clean-architecture-on-android-2e5e8c8e81fe

Good architecture will make your code testable. 
Hope it'll help :)